# Anonymous array accepting null values for int

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-arrays

InquiryOrder Model

```
public class InquiryOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int InquiryOrderId { get; set; }

    public string InquiryOrderName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductType")]
    public int? ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

InquiryOrder Controller

```
var displayedInquiryOrders = filteredInquiryOrders.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);
    var result = from c in displayedInquiryOrders .AsEnumerable()
                  select new[] { 
                            Convert.ToString(c.InquiryOrderId),
                            c.InquiryOrderName,
                            c.ProductType.ProductTypeName,
                        };
```

if `ProductTypeId` has null values in `InquiryOrder` table im getting this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` from `c.ProductType.ProductTypeName` in array. How to adjust this array such that it accepts null values for int. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ProductTypeId` is null, that means that Entity Framework can't lazy load the Product Type for the entity, since it doesn't exist.

That means when you call `c.ProductType.ProductTypeName` `c.ProductType` is null and you get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to get the `ProductTypeName` value.

You can fix this a couple of ways. If you are using the latest version of C# you can use the Null-conditional operator (?.) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

```
select new[] { 
    Convert.ToString(c.InquiryOrderId),
    c.InquiryOrderName,
    c.ProductType?.ProductTypeName,
};
```

If not, you can use a ternary operator to perform the same function:

```
select new[] { 
    Convert.ToString(c.InquiryOrderId),
    c.InquiryOrderName,
    c.ProductType != null ? c.ProductTypeProductTypeName : string.Empty,
};
```

Comment: yes that works. Thanks for the valuable information!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use ternary operator

```
var displayedInquiryOrders = filteredInquiryOrders.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);
var result = from c in displayedInquiryOrders .AsEnumerable()
              select new[] { 
                        Convert.ToString(c.InquiryOrderId),
                        c.InquiryOrderName,
                        c.ProductType != null ? c.ProductType.ProductTypeName : null, //if not null, then add the product type, otherwise add null
                    };
```

In C#6.0, I think you could do it by `?.`

```
var displayedInquiryOrders = filteredInquiryOrders.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);
var result = from c in displayedInquiryOrders .AsEnumerable()
              select new[] { 
                        Convert.ToString(c.InquiryOrderId),
                        c.InquiryOrderName,
                        c.ProductType?.ProductTypeName
                    };
```

Comment: Yes this works. Since `Steve` put the answer first i marked it. But thanks a lot for helping me..